# How to get first list of list depending on element

Tags: python, list

I have List of lists like:

```
[[ac,7,0],[ac,6,1],[ac,5,1],[bc,4,1],[bc,3,0],[ac,2,0]]
```

I need to get all elements of the first list only if

```
elem[2] == 1
```

otherwise, take the all elements of the next list until elem[2] == 1

The result should be:

```
[ac,6,1]
```

I'm new in Python, so I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Please explain the last snippet. What should be your final result? Can you show what the output should be?

Comment: @quamrana Expected result it's elements of the second list. Because i need first list in which element[2]==1

Comment: Does `elem = [x for x in l if x[2] == 1][0]` do the trick? Where `l` is whatever variable name your original list of lists is.

Comment: Or: `elem = next((x for x in l if x[2] == 1), None)` which will find the first instance or set elem to `None` if there is no such list found where `x[2] == 1`.